# Parsing in a long XML file with perl

Tags: xml, perl

Hi everyone im a new perl programmer and im now trying to fetch some data from a long XML file. But i cant to get the two data at the same time in general my code, please i need to check how to use efficiently a loop or any structure to get the data that i need.

```
<item>
    <datetime>7/28/2016 12:00:00 AM - 12:00:15 AM</datetime>
    <datetime_raw>42579.1668402778</datetime_raw>
    <value channel="Traffic Total (volume)" channelid="1">4,664,204 KByte</value>
    <value_raw channel="Traffic Total (volume)" channelid="1">4776145337.3504</value_raw>
    <value channel="Traffic Total (speed)" channelid="1">517,319 kbit/s</value>
    <value_raw channel="Traffic Total (speed)" channelid="1">64664843.4518</value_raw>
    <value channel="Traffic DL (volume)" channelid="2">3,805,763 KByte</value>
    <value_raw channel="Traffic DL (volume)" channelid="2">3897101197.8596</value_raw>
    <value channel="Traffic DL (speed)" channelid="2">422,107 kbit/s</value>
    <value_raw channel="Traffic DL (speed)" channelid="2">52763352.2591</value_raw>
    <value channel="Traffic UL (volume)" channelid="3">858,442 KByte</value>
    <value_raw channel="Traffic UL (volume)" channelid="3">879044139.4907</value_raw>
    <value channel="Traffic UL (speed)" channelid="3">95,212 kbit/s</value>
    <value_raw channel="Traffic UL (speed)" channelid="3">11901491.1927</value_raw>
    <coverage>100 %</coverage>
    <coverage_raw>0000010000</coverage_raw>
   </item>
```

I have hundrends of items like these and i need to extrac the pair datatime and the specific value channel="Traffic Total (volume)" at the same time, here an extract of my perl code:

```
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(string => "$HDF") or die "cannot read file.xml\n";

while ($reader->nextElement( 'item' )) {
                    my $item = $reader->readInnerXml;
                    while ($reader->nextElement( 'datetime' )) {
                        $DT = $reader->readInnerXml;
                        print $DT;

                        while ($reader->nextElement( 'value' )) {
                            my $value = $reader->readInnerXml;
                            if ($value eq 'Traffic Total (speed)'){
                                $HD = $reader->readInnerXml;
                                print $HD;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thanks for your comments about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For long XML, I find [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) has really got it good - it can use `twig_handers` and `purge` as you're parsing, so you can handle subsets of XML efficiently.

So assuming you're wanting to go by "item":

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my @things = ( './datetime', './value[@channel="Traffic Total (speed)"]' );

sub process_item {
   my ( $twig, $item ) = @_;      
   print join "\t", (map { $item -> get_xpath($_,0) -> text } @things),"\n";
   $twig->purge;
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'item' => \&process_item } );
   $twig -> parsefile ('your_file.xml');
```

What `purge` does is discard 'up to this point' from memory, making it quite efficient for XML containing a large number of similar elements.

Comment: I`ve applied the code that you suggest to me, but the result was all the XML file, and as i told you i need only the two mentioned data, thanks for your reply :)

Comment: That code worked with the snipped you provided. What do you mean by 'all the XML file'?